# minus 1500, there are only 12pcs on hand

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Is it correct that I use "minus" in this way to mean taking an amout from a total.

*Minus 1500, there are only 12 pcs on hand.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

Another example:

> We had 600 coins, minus 300 means we only have 300 left

Comment: "Less" is more idiomatic; "minus" is something we say in math lessons.